# Cantor's Theorem Paradox?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Cantor's Theorem states that the cardinality of the power-set of any set is strictly greater than the cardinality of the set. That is to say, that you cannot establish a bijection between a set and its power-set.

I seem to have found two counter-examples, and I would like to know what is my error.

Let's consider the set of natural numbers plus zero, $N=\{0,1,2, ...\}$ and the set of powers of two, $B=\{2^0,2^1,2^2, ...\}$. It is trivial that $|N|=|B|$.

You can easily establish a bijection $f$ between $N$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$ by corresponding every natural number with its binary representation.

$$f(0)\rightarrow \emptyset$$
$$f(1)\rightarrow \{{2^0\}}$$
$$f(2)\rightarrow \{{2^1\}}$$
$$f(3)\rightarrow \{{2^0,2^1\}}$$
$$f(4)\rightarrow \{{2^2\}}$$
$$f(5)\rightarrow \{{2^0,2^2\}}$$

... and so on.

This is a bijection because each natural number has a unique binary representation and any sum of powers of two equals a unique natural number. But this is not possible according to the Cantor's Theorem. (Note: In fact, in my exposition the bijection is between the set and the power-set of a subset, but it is trivially equivalent.)

The other example is even worse and it is based on prime factorization. In this case I use the set of prime numbers, and I proceed in a similar way, but I establish a surjection between the power-set of the primes onto the naturals plus zero.

Each natural number is corresponded with its prime factorization. In this case, each natural number has a unique prime factorization, but every subset of the prime number set is corresponded with infinite natural numbers as seen in the following examples:

$$g(1)\rightarrow \emptyset$$
$$g(2)\rightarrow \{2\}$$
$$g(3)\rightarrow \{3\}$$
$$g(4=2^2)\rightarrow \{2\}$$
$$g(6=2\cdot3)\rightarrow \{2,3\}$$

Implying that $|\mathcal{P}(N)|<|N|$!

Where is the problem?

Comment: For the love of god. I'm tired of seeing that question, over and over and over and over and over again. It's getting tiresome. Someone really needs to make a concentrate thread with all these "dead obvious mistakes" and we can move on. (Nothing personal, Manuel.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila There was (possibly it's still there) a “paper” on arXiv where a guy stated and “proved” that all infinite sets have the same cardinality. It was based on the very same mistake.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Note that the fact that all subsets are finite can be also used to prove the continuum hypothesis, refuting earlier claims that it was independent. The new math is great, isnt it?

Comment: @Rene: I think that it has *far* greater implications for number theory, though.

Answer (score 21):

Your first example is not bijective since it only maps to finite subsets of $B$.

Comment: This is true of the second example too.

Comment: Yes. It's a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

One can certainly argue, using the axiom of choice, that, for any infinite set $S$, the set of finite subsets of $S$ has the same cardinality as $S$. This is what your argument establishes for $\mathbb N$. However, the powerset of $\mathbb N$ has more elements - for instance, the set of all even numbers is a subset of $\mathbb N$. Your function tries to map:
$$2^0+2^2+2^4+\ldots \mapsto \{0,2,4,\ldots\}$$
except, whoops, the left hand side isn't a natural number, so actually, your function is not surjective. This is true of both functions - they map the natural numbers to the *finite* subsets $\mathbb N$, but never to any *infinite* subsets of $\mathbb N$.

If you allow such infinite base-two expansions, more or less, as formal sums, you end up in the [$2$-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), which is somewhat analogous to the real numbers and, analogously, of greater cardinality than the natural numbers.